# c++ version of MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[ESI]

Tags: c++, c, crackme

I'm writing a keygen for a crack-me exercise.

I have a problem with handling byte assignments the crack-me performs several times using instructions like `MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[ESI]` (move byte from location to AL) to change `EAX` for example from `000096BA` to `00009662`.

The crack-me overflows `EAX` value several times so to calculate the key I use an `unsigned int` in my C program.

The problem I have is that I do not know how I can replace a single byte value in `unsigned int` example from `0x38586d` to `0x38498d`, changing the second byte only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int eax;
char * esi;
*((char *) &eax) = *esi;
```

Comment: It is better to provide a thorough explanation alongside the final answer

Comment: &eax takes the address of eax and has the type `int *` 
(char *) &eax casts the int * to a char *.
*((char *) &eax) references the char (byte) pointed to by the char *.
= assigns the char / byte pointed to by esi to the first byte of eax. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

First, most decent compilers will let you introduce assembly directly in your C code. This is not recommended but the option should be noted.

Now, here's a sane solution; C was several [bitwise operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm) to manipulate sets of bits inside an integer.

The bitwise operators we'll use here are:

1. binary AND operator (`&`):

   A bit in the result variable is only set if it was set in both input variables. For example, `0b0011 & 0b1010` will result in `0b0010`.
2. binary OR operator (`|`)

   A bit in the result variable will be set if it was set in at least one of the input variables. For example, `0b0011 | 0b1010` will result in `0b1011`.
3. binary NOT operator (`~`)

   A bit in the result variable will only be set if it was *not* set in the input variable. For example, `~0b0001` will result in `0b1110`.
4. arithmetic shift operator (`<<`)

   A bit in the result variable will only be set if the bit  `n` positions to the right in the first variable was set, where `n` is the second variable. If that position does not exist, the bit is not set. For example, `0b0000 0b0101 << 2` will result in `0b0001 0b0100`.

And here's how we could use them to set the *lowest* byte in dword `a` to that of char `c`, assuming a 32bit processor for simplicity's sake:

```
unsigned int a = 0xa5a5a505;
unsigned char c = 0xa0;
```

First, we'll want to zero-out the lowest byte. We'll do that by ANDing the dword with a dword that has all of it's bits set *except* the 8 lowest bits (aka it's lowest byte).

```
a = a & 0xffffff00
```

Alternatively, we can use the NOT binary operator to create `0xffffff00` in a slightly cleaner manner, as follows:

```
a = a & ~0xff
```

After either of those lines, which perform exactly the same thing (and will look identical in assembly), `a`'s value would be `0xa5a5a500`.

Now, we'll need to assign the value of `c` to that same byte. We'll use the OR bitwise operator in the following manner:

```
a = a | c;
```

Which will result in `a` having the value of `0xa5a5a5a0`.

Now, if we would like to do the same for the 2nd byte in the integer we'll shift the values by 8 bits before executing the same operators, like this:

```
a = a & ~(0xff << 8)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = a & ~(0xff00)
```

Which is identical to:

```
a = a & 0xffff00ff
```

Which will result with:

```
a = 0xa5a50005
```

And now, we'll add `c` at the 2nd byte's position:

```
a = a | (c << 8)
```

Which in our example is:

```
a = a | 0xa000
```

Which will result in `0xa5a5a005`